I have 9 million raw camera photography files
I feel like it's an albatross. That said, it's my passion. I make photography part of my everyday life. And these 9 million files mean a lot to me. 16 TB of happiness.
It's why I've stayed on Windows. Most of my life. I've tried out Ubuntu budgie and found it to be a good home.
I strongly dislike Windows. And would really like to find a good backup plan. I've been using backblaze for a decade. And it seems to work quite well. I had a loss of data some time ago. And I was able to restore using backblaze.
How can I have a similar backup plan; Working in the background; Using Ubuntu?

What is your question exactly?

Unfortunately, product recommendations are generally off topic here, especially commercial products that are not integral to Ubuntu.   Having said that, there appears to be a Blackblaze linux client, so I don't see why you can't continue with what you have.   Any questions about Blackblaze need to be addressed to the company directly, not to an Ubuntu forum.

with that number of photos, you might be better off storing them on a NAS such as Synology Photos which is designed for the purpose which comes with its own backup strategies.

With that number of photos, you might be better off storing them on a NAS such as Synology Photos which is designed for the purpose and comes with its own backup strategies.
Key Features

Good things are meant to be shared. Securely share photos with other users or anyone else with restricted file access.

Enable mobile backup and synchronize all images on your Android or iOS device to Synology NAS. Free up space on your device without losing content.

The Synology Photos TV app is available on Apple TV and Android TV. View photos and videos on the big screen via the TV app or by casting through AirPlay or Chromecast.


And, specifically with regards backup/restore
With Hyper Backup -Synology's proprietary backup tool, you can back up Synology Photos to local or remote destinations and restore the settings and data of the package to a previous point in time.
The following data will be backed up once a task is created:

All the photos, videos, created albums, and folders
The recognition results in the People, Subjects, and Places albums
Synology Photos package settings and share link settings


Just out of curiosity as a benchmark, how good is this fancy technology? ho long will it take for 1 GB data?

@Rishon_JR much will depend on many factors not least of which the speed and nature of the connection of the source to the NAS (if you are referring to populating the NAS from the existing source). You may find this Reddit question helpful in answering your question otherwise
